# Reduce or Solve to solve 3 simultaneous equations/inequalities

Tags: equation-solving, inequalities

I've tried both ways, and maybe it justtakes Mathematica a long time to solve this system of equations, but I can't tell if it is hung up or crunching.  So, I'm wondering im y approach with mathematica is wrong in the first place:

```
eq1=(0.0000472222 C1 R1)/(1. C1^2 R1^2 + C2 (0.0051 + (0.0000472222 + 108. C1) R1 + 1. C1 R1^2)) <= \[Pi]/4

eq2=(14.0028 C1 R1 Sqrt[C1 R1 + C2 (108 + R1)] (C1 R1 (1.35525*10^-20 + 1. C1 R1) + C2 (0.0051 + (0.0000472222 + 108. C1) R1 + 1. C1 R1^2)))/(Sqrt[C1 C2 R1] (1. C1^2 R1^2 + C2 (0.0051 + (0.0000472222 + 108. C1) R1 + 1. C1 R1^2))) >= 60

eq3= (2.22861 Sqrt[C1 R1 + C2 (108 + R1)])/Sqrt[C1 C2 R1] >= 220000
```

I've tried

```
Reduce[{eq3, eq4, eq5, R1 > 0, C1 > 0, C2 > 0, C1 > C2}, {C1, C2, R1}, Reals]
```

and

```
Solve[eq3 && eq4 && eq5 && R1 > 0 && C1 > 0 && C2 > 0 && C1 > C2, {C1, C2, R1}, Reals]
```

but it's either not working, or just taking a lot longer than I expect it to (and I should just let it run longer)

Is there a way for me to know if it is crunching or hung up?
Is there a better way to solve this system in Mathematica? Should I be constraining the possible values of R1, C1, and C2 better or more?

Thanks for the help

Comment: see if  `FindInstance` finds any solution

Comment: Trying it now...has been crunching for 20min....seems to be similar Solve and Reduce - I'm letting it run for a while to see what happens. Thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Can you plot these three equations to see about where they intersect, or to make sure there is an intersection point?

Comment: it may help if you rationalize all of the floating point stuff ( 0.0051 -> 51/10000 , etc )

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions....@Tom, can you suggest how I could plot these equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rather have seen the inequalities in the Laplace Transform (sL and 1 / (sC)). But it goes like this.
First we make equations from the inequalities, apply rationalization, and compute R1. We use FindInstance to find C1 and C2.

```
eq1 = (0.0000472222 C1 R1)/(1. C1^2 R1^2 + C2 (0.0051 + (0.0000472222 + 108. C1) R1 + 1. C1 R1^2)) - π/4;
eq2 = (14.0028 C1 R1 Sqrt[C1 R1 + C2 (108 + R1)] (C1 R1 (1.35525*10^-20 + 1. C1 R1) + C2 (0.0051 + (0.0000472222 + 108. C1) R1 + 1. C1 R1^2)))/(Sqrt[C1 C2 R1] (1. C1^2 R1^2 + 
        C2 (0.0051 + (0.0000472222 + 108. C1) R1 + 1. C1 R1^2))) - 60;
eq3 = (2.22861 Sqrt[C1 R1 + C2 (108 + R1)])/Sqrt[C1 C2 R1] - 220000;

eq11 = Rationalize[eq1, 0];
eq22 = Rationalize[eq2, 0];
eq33 = Rationalize[eq3, 0];

R1 = R1 /. First@Solve[eq33 == 0, R1];
solC1C2 = First@FindInstance[{eq11 == 0, eq22 == 0}, {C1, C2}] // N
{C1 -> 6.59944*10^-10, C2 -> 1.21549*10^-10}

R1 /. solC1C2
65772.
```

The absolute error is in the range of machine accuracy.

```
{eq1, eq2, eq3} /. solC1C2
{1.45106*10^-13, -1.29887*10^-11, 2.91038*10^-11}
```

To answer your last question in your comment:
Fortunately, the inequalities have the form greater than or equal to and less than or equal to!!!

You can do the same calculation with your inequalities. It's then difficult to calculate R1.

```
eq1 = (0.0000472222 C1 R1)/(1. C1^2 R1^2 + C2 (0.0051 + (0.0000472222 + 108. C1) R1 + 1. C1 R1^2)) <= π/4;
eq2 = (14.0028 C1 R1 Sqrt[C1 R1 + C2 (108 + R1)] (C1 R1 (1.35525*10^-20 + 1. C1 R1) + C2 (0.0051 + (0.0000472222 + 108. C1) R1 + 1. C1 R1^2)))/(Sqrt[C1 C2 R1] (1. C1^2 R1^2 + 
        C2 (0.0051 + (0.0000472222 + 108. C1) R1 + 1. C1 R1^2))) >= 60;
eq3 = (2.22861 Sqrt[C1 R1 + C2 (108 + R1)])/Sqrt[C1 C2 R1] >= 220000;

eq11 = Rationalize[eq1, 0];
eq22 = Rationalize[eq2, 0];
eq33 = Rationalize[eq3, 0];

solR1 = Simplify[Reduce[eq33, R1], C1 > 0 && C2 > 0] // N
```

[image]

We already have a solution for R1, C1, and C2 and check whether this condition for R1 is met by using the calculated values.

```
R1 = 65772;
sol = {C1 -> 6.59944*10^-10, C2 -> 1.21549*10^-10};
solR1 /. sol
{True}
```

Comment: Success!! Thank you very much!  I've been at this for the better part of 2 days trying to manipulate this so that Mathematica could solve the system of equations.  Excellent.  I tried voting this answer up, but I don't have enough reputation to be able to do so.  Apologies.
What would the approach to solve these as inequalities instead ?  For example, eq1 <= pi/4, eq2 >=60, eq3>=220000?

Comment: @jrive I have tried to answer your last question.

Comment: Excellent, @rewi-  thanks again. I will play with this some more to understand.

Comment: did it take a long time for you as well for Mathematica to do the Reduce function?

Comment: @jrive On my notebook it takes 0.76s, provided the terms were rationalized.

Comment: Ok- here is what I learned yesterday.  It makes a difference how I define the equations even though they are equivalent.  For example, if equation 1 is presented as in the posting, it works.  In that case, I substituted some known values , simplified the resulting equation, and then subtracted $$\pi/4$$ .  The  simplified result looks much more complicated, and the solver chokes when it tries to find a solution for C1 and C2 (I'm referring to the version where the equations are equalities).   @rewi, would you be willing to take a look to see what I mean?  I can send you the notebook.

Comment: to clarify comment above, @rewi, (I read it and it doesn;t quite make sense, but for some reason, I can't edit it!), in one case I simplify the expression that generates eq 1, for example, and then subtract $\frac{\pi}{4}$.  This is what i did so I could post the equations in the original posting.  If instead I first subtract $\frac{\pi}{4}$ from the expression and then simplify (and take a similar approach with the other 2 equations) Mathematica cannot seem to find a solution. The resulting expressions are way more complicated (although equivalent). Not sure what is tripping Mathematica up.

Comment: @jrive Mathematica sometimes appears to be very "obtrusive". My way of solving the equation system was well thought out. Maybe there are other solutions, I do not know. Ultimately, I hope to have helped you.

Comment: you have @rewi, much appreciated.